# Como usar componentes iniciais diferentes no Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Eu tenho um aplicativo Blazor Server e migrei para o modelo Blazor App, porém preciso executar ele com `<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />` no `App.razor` pra evitar que quebre. Mas quero poder usar o rendermode por página/componente. A minha ideia seria ir refatorando ele aos poucos para que todos os componentes e páginas não sejam dependente do `InteractiveServer`. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Algo que eu tinha pensado era em definir componentes inicias diferentes, mas não consegui encontrar uma maneira de fazer isso.

Tentando exemplificar o que quero dizer, seria algo semelhante como abaixo:

**Obs.: É apenas um exemplo. Eu sei que o código abaixo não funciona.**

```cs
// Rotas específicas que já foram refatoradas, com o componente NewApp.razor.
string[] newRoutes = ["/example/examplePage", "/example/otherExamplePage"];
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(newRoutes), config =>
    config.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        endpoints.MapRazorComponents<NewApp>()
            .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()));

// Todas as outras rotas, com o componente App.razor.
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```